# How to iterate over the current object in an array and only print the values in Handlebars?

Tags: handlebars.js

Consider this array :

```
var urls = [
     { alias : 'home',
       path : '/page/home',
       title: 'Home',
       desc : 'simple test'
     },
    { alias : 'home1',
       path : '/page/home1',
       title: 'Home1',
       desc : 'simple test1'
     },
    { alias : 'home2',
       path : '/page/home2',
       title: 'Home2',
       desc : 'simple test2'
     },
];
```

How can I iterate over all the properties inside an object in the array and print their values? I don't care about the names of the properties.

I would like to do someting like:

```
{{#urls}}
   <tr>
   {{#each .}}
     <td>
     {{value}}
     </td>
   {{/each}}
   </tr>
{{/urls}}
```

And this would output

```
<tr><td>home</td><td>/page/home</td><td>Home</td><td>simple test</td></tr>
<tr><td>home1</td><td>/page/home1</td><td>Home1</td><td>simple test1</td></tr>
<tr><td>home2</td><td>/page/home2</td><td>Home2</td><td>simple test2</td></tr>
```

I don't want to type:

```
{{#urls}}
   <tr>
     <td>
     {{alias}}
     </td>
     <td>
     {{path}}
     </td>
     <td>
     {{title}}
     </td>
     <td>
     {{desc}}
     </td>
   </tr>
{{/urls}}
```

I might have more than 10 properties so I don't want to type their names anywhere I want to iterate over them.

My problem is I don't know how to access the current object in iteration or pass it to a helper. Do you know how to do that in Handlebars?

I don't want to put the values in arrays instead because I still need to see the properties for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X9HCF/5/)

Helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('renderUrl', function(urls) {
    var dom = '';

    urls.forEach(function (url) {
        dom += '<tr>';

        for(key in url) {
            dom += '<td>' + url[key] + '</td>'
        }

        dom += '</tr>';
    });

    return new Handlebars.SafeString(dom);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to type the names of the properties. I might have more than 10 properties I want to iterate over them without typing their names.

Comment: @eloone Is this what you want or something else more?

Comment: Your solution here works great for the front, but I am trying to make it work on the server, I have tried to apply your helper on the server but I think I can make it work just with {{#each .}}{{value}}{{/each}}